# How to measure the startup time of JBOSS 7 server?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss7.x

I want to compare JBOSS 5 with 7. The documentation says that JBOSS 7 is much quicker.
How do I proceed?

Edit1:
I don't have any app. Just want to dry test it.

Edit2:

> 13:45:11,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss AS
>   7.0.0.Final "Lightning" started in 1836ms - Started 92 of 147 services
>   (55 services are passive or on-demand)

I looked at the log files and got the startup time.
Now, is it fair to compare this startup time to JBOSS 5 because the log file says "Started 92 of 147 services"  So how do we compare both of them when each starts different number of services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your edit, the start up time is indicated in the logs, as you also saw.

About your question if this means comparing apples to oranges because JBoss 5 and 7 are going to start different services, I think that it may be true. Actually if your application server starts in under two seconds, it's good enough, it doesn't matter any more. What you should care about is the performance of your application to user requests.